# CoreAudio: What is "AudioBox" as contrasted to "AudioDevice"

Tags: macos, core-audio

The header file **CoreAudio/AudioHardware.h** refers to a class "`AudioBox`" and indicates that it is distinct from but related to the class "`AudioDevice`". Searching developer.apple.com yields no hits for AudioBox. There is, unfortunately, a commercial product called AudioBox™, which makes googling for the term painfully low-yield.

Here are the comments containing the references:

> ```
> kAudioHardwarePropertyBoxList
> ```
>
> An array of AudioObjectIDs that represent all the **AudioBox**
>   objects currently    provided by the system.
>
> ```
> kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateUIDToBox
> ```
>
> This property fetches the AudioObjectID that corresponds to the
>   **AudioBox**    that has the given UID. The UID is passed in via the qualifier as a CFString    while the AudioObjectID for the AudioBox is
>   returned to the caller as the    property's data. Note that an error
>   is not returned if the UID doesn't refer    to any **AudioBox**es.
>   Rather, this property will return `kAudioObjectUnknown` as the value of the property.

The header file: **AudioHardwareBase.h** contains numerous references to AudioBox, but does not define or explain it, although it *associates* it with AudioDevice.

Searching the docs via XCode just takes me back to AudioHardwareBase.h.

I can *infer* that *perhaps* an "AudioBox" is an audio device that is accessed via a plugin. But this does not appear to be stated anywhere.

### **So What Is An AudioBox?**

Comment: An AudioBox is a container of (usually) AudioDevices.

Answer (score 4):

An `AudioBox` is a container of (usually) `AudioDevices`

Comment: Indeed, `AudioHardwareBase.h` also says that: "An AudioBox is a container for other objects (typically AudioDevice objects)."